# Executing a script upon receiving a http post request on my Node server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I have a node server that recieves http POST messages from my chrome extension.

javascript:

```
  function RecieveMessage(req, res) {
    console.log("got the message"
     }
```

I would like to know how to execute a another JS file held on my node server when a message is received by the RecieveMessage function? What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood, this should do it:

```
var otherFile = require('./otherfile.js');
...
function RecieveMessage(req, res) {
  console.log("got the message");
  otherFile(args);
}
```

And your `otherfile.js' should expose a main function like this:

```
module.exports = function (args) {
  // Your code goes in here
};
```

Comment: Thanks, What is I wanted to input the 'res' from the RecieveMessage function into my 'otherfile.js'? Would something like res.write work with this?

Comment: if your otherfile.js has all it's code wrapped in `module.exports = function (res) { /* your code */ };`, then the above would work.

You're  talking about taking `res` and passing it as an argument to a function - that function can just be another file using `module.exports` and `require`.

Comment: What does your other code do with `res`? It might help to know that.